# How to make a Firefox profile link on the Desktop of a Mac?

Tags: mac, desktop, links

I want to a link file on Desktop just like windows for:

```
/Volumes/Mackintosh HD/Applications/Firefox.app -p -no-remote "politics_x64"
```

In other words, please imagine there is a link file named `1.lnk` on Desktop. If double-clicked this link file, then it will open:

```
/Volumes/Mackintosh HD/Applications/Firefox.app -p -no-remote "politics_x64"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `bash` script on the desktop like this:

```
nano ~/Desktop/Firefox_Launcher.sh
```

And add this stuff into that file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

open /Applications/Firefox.app -p -no-remote "politics_x64"
```

In `nano` you can then save the file by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and type in `Y` to save the file.

Once saved you should set the permissions on the file to run it like this:

```
chmod 755 ~/Desktop/Firefox_Launcher.sh
```

And now you can run that from the terminal like this:

```
~/Desktop/Firefox_Launcher.sh
```

But if you want to double click it, make sure that file is associated with “Terminal” by doing a “Get Info” on the file and making sure the “Open with:” is set to “Terminal.”

Comment: Thanks, but I have a further question. I changed into this code  - open /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P -no-remote "politics_x64" -. But I got an errr message.    'code' open /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P -no-remote "politics_x64" '/code'

Comment: And the "Firefox_Launcher.sh" file at the Desktop is not excuted by double-clicking. But opened by texteditor.

Comment: This code works. - /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --P -no-remote politics_x64 -.

And needed this command.

chmod +x ~/Desktop/Firefox_Launcher.sh

Comment: Sorry. I voted and checked now.